# Set Add To Path in Inno Setup in Windows using the Registry

Tags: windows, path, registry, inno-setup

I'm making an installer in Inno Setup.

I've set my script alright, and it can installed in both administrative mode as well as non-administrative mode.

But the problem here is, I need to add my application's folder to `Path` environment variable.

If I write to the Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, it would make non-admin not able to use the Run dialog or cmd or powershell or something to launch my application.

If I write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`, then all the users may not be able to use the feature when admin privileges are available.

So, I am looking for someone to help me on this.

Comment: You can use the IsAdmin function [see https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp ] to determine whether to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` or to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`

Comment: I would recommend using [PathMgr.dll](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr) - it supports per-machine and per-user, prevents redundant additions of the path when reinstall/downgrade/upgrade, and more.

Comment: *"If I write to the Registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, it would make non-admin not able to use the Run dialog or cmd or powershell or something to launch my application"* – Why? What you store that should be added to `PATH` of all users.